# How to force WinXP to ask for password before software installation/uninstall?

Tags: linux, windows-xp, installation, security, uninstall

I really like some of the linux security measures it uses.

So what i'd like to do is have WinXP Pro SP3 ask for my user password everytime i try to install/remove software.

I know I can't make windows be as secure as linux, but i'd love to adopt some of the great ideas and measures used, as possible, to make windows more secure.

Any suggestions?

P.S. Are there other people out there, who try to make their windows feel more linux like? Just curious.

Comment: My ps question, was referring to those who customize their desktops, to have a linux-like feel to them. My main problem is that I am stuck with my current hardware, and I have tried Windows 7, and my hardware can not work with it. So I am trying to find out what I can do to tighten my security.

Answer (score 0):

This feature already exists in all supported versions of Windows (namely Vista and above). It's called UAC.

If you set yourself up as a normal (standard) user and attempt to install software you will be immediately prompted for an administrator password.

Comment: Unfortunately, my question is for WinXP Pro SP3. I was hoping for some registry or group policy I could create, that would do this.

Comment: To do this on the unsupported operating system of Windows XP SP3 (which has numerous serious performance and security problems compared to in-service editions of Windows - you really need to upgrade), try creating your account as a standard user rather than an administrator. Your account will then not be able to edit files and folders under the "Program Files" directory.

Comment: Doesn't that just block installing software, or does it ask for my password? Because what i'd like to happen, is that as I try to install software it automatically asks for my password. Yes, I could upgrade my OS but my hardware isn't supported by newer OSES, so that options is not available to me.

Comment: It blocks installing software _from your account_ and then requires you to login as an administrator to run the installer (e.g. via "runas").

Comment: Also, I don't mean to be unkind, but complaining that you "can't make Windows as secure as Linux" and then refusing to actually upgrade to take advantage of any of the kernel protections introduced in the past twelve years is completely nonsensical. WindowsXP is _Massively_ less secure than Windows7. Just upgrade already. Windows7 is faster, more secure and has the huge advantage of actually being actively supported by Microsoft.

Comment: Since I can't afford new computer or hardware, and windows 7, doesn't support my hardware, my only option is switch 100% to linux or stay at Windows xp. So i have no choice but to make the most of it. Yes I know WinXP has holes, some of us don't have the luxury of being able to afford new pc's, so we must do with what we do have.

Comment: I am not trying to make windows like linux, only to see if some of the concepts and ideas are applicable. I am trying to be creative and find ways to do things with the hardware I have, and OS that works with my current hardware.